# Extracting bytes from a byte array one by one (C)

Tags: c

I have a byte array (dB). I am trying to extract the bytes one by one. Why isn't this code working? Any pointers? Logically am I wrong? Or something wrong with my implementation?

Comment: Can you show all the code. Otherwise we have to guess what type your variables are.

Comment: What does "not working" mean? A failure during compilation? If so, please provide the error messages. Are you referring to a segfault? If so, please provide your code, in it's compilable form. Logically you are wrong by asking us a question, because you haven't provided us enough information to answer the question.

Comment: `unsigned int` doesn't sound like it's going to be a byte, since `int` is guaranteed to be at least 16 bits long. Unless you're on a very funky platform where a byte is 16 bits. :x

Comment: Did you forget the actual loop?

Comment: Assuming you have a sensible reason for not just using `db[dOffset];`, I suggest you compare that with the result of your function in a debugger.

Comment: Use unsigned char instead of unsigned int. char is the only C type which takes just one byte of memory

Comment: why all those extra code?1). if you want a byte from a byte array use bytearray[offset] ie. db[offset]. 2). if you want all the bytes use it in a loop.3). if you want to convert each byte to int then have an int array and store it(casting is implicit).

Comment: unsigned char *dB= (unsigned char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
^^ This is dB and i am getting 'error C2107: illegal index, indirection not allowed' ---AND--- 'getByte' : too few arguments' for tmp = getByte(&dB[dOffset]); dOffset++;

Actual loop is still there, I've just posted the logic here.

Comment: this is just all kinds of wrong : `int* offset= &offset;` ... seeing that makes me think you should probably go over the entire code, and double-check everything.

Answer (score 1):

You have byte buffers declared like this:

```
unsigned char *decodeBuf;
```

To read a single value from that buffer, at offset `i` you simply write:

```
unsigned char b = decodeBuf[i];
```

Comment: @WhozCraig Sorry, I mis-read the code. Like an amateur.  :-(

Comment: Pfft. you've *forgotten* more about WIN32 programming than I can remember, and I've been at this for 22 years. No worries, mate.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
int main()
{
    unsigned char tmp;
    tmp = getByte(dB+dOffset); dOffset++;
}
```

it should work

Comment: Encoding is working fine and tested.

Comment: check this out http://codepad.org/MoKuOaCJ

Comment: Working fine ;) Going back to the pitch ;) 3 wickets down ;) Thank you :)